# JSP-How to generate a unique link for users?

Tags: jsp, web

I have came across this issue in which I ponder on thinking any possible suggestion to make a fool proof URL.

So I have a web application and it contains some files.Each file has it's own unique id,in my case I callled them node ID.I am planning to generate a unique link for a file and need some advice.

Firstly,my JSP that displays the file when I paste the URL is in this format:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/pantonpaper/flexpaper/flexer.jsp?nodeID=27484&graphID=22026&widgetID=22027
```

The idea is if I want to generate a unique link of the file and send it to the other user to view this file. He gets this link and copy and paste it and views the file on the browser.The problem is the other user decides to change the nodeID value,say 27488,then he will be able to view the other file that is tied to this ID.

I am trying to prevent this from happening by making it as fool proof as possible. I couldn't think of a good way that will prevent them from doing so.

I would appreciate any suggestion to achieve this goal.

Comment: Have you tried using UUID for nodeid instead of numeric value ?

Comment: But my URL only works in this format nodeID=xxx graphid=xxx etc

Comment: Because it grabs the nodeID from my table to find the file

Comment: same URL.... generate node ID with java UUID API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html ...also persist node id in database oracle supports UUID data type

Comment: The link you sent is invalid. Also, care to explain more about this?

Comment: linkupdated...UUID API generates unique identifier across all JVM and possibility of duplicate is very rare...your problem is that node id is running sequence of numeric value so end user can change its value and view other files but structure of UUID will not allow the user to do that and guessing value of UUID will also difficult, also you should implement authorization framework which will allow users with permission to view files

Comment: problem is they do not need to have permission to view the URL

Comment: Is there a way that i can "hide" the paramaters of the url so when the user paste the URL, he doesn't see the parameters and still able to view it